# Algorithm for Finding the Center of an Optimal Stereographic Projection

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry

given a fnite set $\mathcal{P}$ of points on a $n$-sphere $\mathcal{S}$ and, define a function $f:(s,\mathcal{P})\mapsto\mathbb{R}_0^+$, that maps each point $s$ on $\mathcal{S}$ to the $n$-volume $Vol\left(CH\left(s,\mathcal{P}\right)\right)$bound by the convex hull of the image $\mathcal{P}'$ of $\mathcal{P}$, when stereographically projected from $s$ onto the antipodal tangent-plane,

> how can an optimal such $s$ be calculated, that yields the smallest $Vol\left(CH\left(s,\mathcal{P}\right)\right)$?

The motivation for my question is to find a definition for convex hulls on spheres, that is also meaningful, if no empty half-space contains the sphere-center.